# Handle State as new Route in Ionic Framework with Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic Framework with its AngularJS UI-Router and $stateProvider to handle different views in my app.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell the $stateProvider that I got different "Main View's", with each having different Subviews.

When I'm on `/#/home` for example, and click on a link which sends me to `/#/about`, then `/#/about` doesn't get rendered as it's own, new view. Instead it transitions to it as it were a subpage of `/#/home`.

It works like it should when I replace $stateProvider with the AngularJS $routeProvider, but then all the transitions are gone.

I've created a Pen for you to take a look at it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBDFi

There should be no transition between them. Every "base" url should be a new "tab".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'subpages'. Add `hide-back-button="true"` to both views (`<view></view>`) and remove the `animation="slide-left-right"` from `<nav-view></nav-view>`. Is that what you are trying to achieve? But then only when switching between your 'main views'?

Comment: almost! That is exactly the behaviour I'm trying to achieve. But I want to keep the sliding animation for `subpages`. And with `subpages` I mean for example `/#/about/tom` where `tom` is a subpage of `/#/about`.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this is still relevant as it was posted February and I'm by no means a ng-pro but here is my attempt [JSBinLink](http://jsbin.com/dolamuhu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Two major things I did where to wrap the content in ion-tabs and add it in the stateProvider as an abstract state.

With this construct you have two independent tabs "Home", "About" - notice, no back button.
However if you navigate to "Tom" within "About" - you get a back button.

There are other ways to achieve something similar, one is to create child states and such.

I would recommend to check out the UI-Routers documentation. 
It's mostly well written and very informative - there is also a create video of Tom Kindberg explaining the main concepts of it over [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqJRoh8MnBo).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between $StateRouteProvider and $UrlRouteProvider ..

$UrlRouteProvider.otherwise(url);
-->route to given url.

$StateRouteProvider.otherwise(state);
-->route to given state.

So, if you are using ui-router then wherever view change is required use $state.go(). In a case of $location.path(URL) will work in a case like the transition to the independent state to current state. If you are looking to route through states under the same parent then you have to use $state route.