# With angularjs and ui-router, how to disable the navigator history for one view change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want the current state change not to be saved in navigation history. Then when user clicks 'back', the view will be skipped and go back to previous page.

Can I temporally disable the state change to be saved in navigator history?

Answer (score 6):

I believe this where ui-router's option parameter with value [{ location:'replace'}](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) is intended for.

The documentation explains:

> location Boolean or "replace" (default true), If true will update the
>   url in the location bar, if false will not. If string "replace", will
>   update url and also replace last history record.

It seems that there's an issue (see it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1007)) to be fixed though.

Comment: Hmz I see the usecase coming along at several other places:https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1287
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628169/handle-state-as-new-route-in-ionic-framework-with-angular-ui-router

Comment: This seems to be a way. I will try later.

Comment: by the way, although there is an options `{lication: 'replace'}`, but this is not working. As mentioned in answer, there is an issue about that, and not fixed yet. At least not fixed in 1.3.18 when I tried.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of stackoverflow I will try to answer the question and not mention that what you are asking for is a truly horrible hack ;-)

I think you may need something like this. (the code is coffeescript)

```
angular
.module 'app', ['ui.router']
.run ($rootScope, $state) ->
    $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeStart', (event) =>
        if $state.is 'bad-state'
            event.preventDefault()
            $state.go 'good-state'
```

When the location changes (you could also use `$stateChangeStart`) you check the current state and if it is the state you don't want then you go to the state you do want. the `event.preventDefault()` effectively halts the processing of the originally requested state.

If you need an even dirtier version then you could check the location urls instead of the states and use `$location.url` to perform the transfer, like this:

```
angular
.module 'app', ['ui.router']
.run ($rootScope, $location) ->
    $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeStart', (event, nextLocation) =>
        if nextLocation is '/bad/location'
            event.preventDefault()
            $location.path '/good/location'
```

Comment: This is what I did now, I hope there is a nice way to implement this, like disabling the navi temporality.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
   event.preventDefault();
   window.history.forward();
});
```